# Intro to 2D Graphics: feedback request

Tags: discussion

Perhaps Off Topic.

I find it useful when learning something to write a tutorial, mostly to myself but perhaps of interest to others.  I've written one for the basics of 2D graphics and was looking for feedback - not about what to include (I'm OK with that at this moment) but mostly in the "oops, you've got that bit messed up which will cause major problems for you down the line - better to start with *foo* not *bar*".

[mma Graphics Intro](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BzuyQLmQu7AwT2xXSFU5Y0x0Tms), Pages: 12, Type: pdf

Comment: I like the idea and attitude. But I can't help the fact that such question won't fit main mma.SE or mma.meta.se rules :-/ It will be too broad / opinion based for the main and meta is about the network itself. I think I saw this question on community.wolfram.com, right? This would be the right place to review as it is more discussion friendly. pro tip, edit the question from time to time so it pops up on the main.

Comment: Thanks Kuba, that was my first thought too but I didn't seem to be able to generate any interest over there - hence the repost.  I'll take your comment on board though and refrain from submitting similar in future.

Comment: Another idea is to ask here on chat and maybe you will get some feedback via e-mail or maybe a separate chat could be created.

Comment: Chat? WTF is chat? ooohhh....  thanks, I'll be lurking over there for the foreseeable future ;-)

Comment: ? http://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=mathematica.stackexchange.com